# Failed to instantiate [java.util.concurrent.Executor]: Illegal arguments to factory method 'getAsyncExecutor'; args: ; nested excep

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-async

When I upgraded in SpringBoot, I have a problem:

> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [java.util.concurrent.Executor]: Illegal arguments to
> factory method 'getAsyncExecutor'; args: ; nested excep

My Code is :

```java
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExecutorConfig.class);

    @Primary
    @Override
    @Bean
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        // 设置核心线程数
        threadPool.setCorePoolSize(10);
        // 设置最大线程数
        threadPool.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        // 线程池所使用的缓冲队列
        threadPool.setQueueCapacity(250);
        // 等待任务在关机时完成--表明等待所有线程执行完
        threadPool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        // 等待时间 （默认为0，此时立即停止），并没等待xx秒后强制停止
        threadPool.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        // 线程名称前缀
        threadPool.setThreadNamePrefix("MyAsync-");


        // 初始化线程
        threadPool.initialize();

        return threadPool;
    }


    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        return new MyAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

    /**
     * 自定义异常处理类
     *
     * @author hry
     *
     */
    class MyAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
        // 手动处理捕获的异常
        @Override
        public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {
                System.out.println("-------------》》》捕获线程异常信息");
                logger.info("Exception message - " + throwable.getMessage());
                logger.info("Method name - " + method.getName());
                for (Object param : obj) {
                    logger.info("Parameter value - " + param);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

When I removed AsyncConfigurer, my SpringBoot project started normally. Why?
My SpringBoot version was upgraded from 2.1.2 to 2.7.16 and SpringCloud version is 2.1.2.RELEASE upgraded to 2021.0.4.0.
Thanks.

Comment: what is the java version? can you update with build.gradle or pom.xml? what spring-cloud feature is used?

Answer (score 0):

If you override `AsyncConfigurer` interface, it is not a fully managed Spring bean otherwise add the `@Bean` annotation remove method `executor.initialize()` in the getAsyncExecutor() method if you want a fully managed bean.

Refer to this document https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

     @Override
     public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
         ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
         executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
         executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
         executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
         executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
         executor.initialize();
         return executor;
     }

     @Override
     public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
         return new MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
     }
 }
```

> Note: In the above example the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is not a fully managed Spring bean. Add the @Bean annotation to the getAsyncExecutor() method if you want a fully managed bean. In such circumstances it is no longer necessary to manually call the executor.initialize() method as this will be invoked automatically when the bean is initialized.